# How to use JKAutoShrinkView or GTScrollNavigationBar with storyboard

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to use [JKAutoShrinkView](https://github.com/fsjack/JKAutoShrinkView) but I am using storyboard and I am not sure how to translate the following notion:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[JKAutoShrinkNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:[JKAutoShrinkToolbar class]];
    [navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [navigationController setAutoNavigationBarShirnkEnabled:YES];
    [navigationController setAutoToolbarShirnkEnabled:YES];

    JKViewController *viewController = [[JKViewController alloc] init];
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

    return YES;
}
```

The same approach is taken by [GTScrollNavigationBar](https://github.com/luugiathuy/GTScrollNavigationBar). Basically, what is the storyboard equivalent? I am supposing the problem piece to be `initWithNavigationBarClass`. But someone who knows should be able to tell me how the translation goes.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the class of Navigation Bar to GTScrollNavigationBar from storyboard in your Navigation Controller Scene

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works. Don't know why He didn't accept the answer.